# ElasticSearch nested query score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index :

```
PUT my_index2
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two documents:

```
POST my_index2/my_type/
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "Alice Don"
    },
    {
      "name": "Smith"
    }
  ]
}

POST my_index2/my_type/
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "Alice David"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I search it:

```
GET my_index2/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "user",

            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                    { "match" : {"user.name" : "Alice"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although both documents have one "Alice", the score of the first one is higher. How could that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your first document has shorter "name", so you got more same chars between "query" and "name"